# EventMachine and some Ruby syntax

Tags: ruby, syntax, line, eventmachine

I'm trying to get a better understanding of the following lines of code involving EventMachine. Trying to learn Ruby the hard way.

What does EventMachine.run does in this code?

What does |chunk| means in this case?

Also, what does 'while line' does? Is line a Ruby syntax? I couldn't seem to find anything related to that.

```
#create an HTTP request ob to URL above with user authorization
EventMachine.run do
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get :head => { 'Authorization' => [ user, password ] }

# Initiate an empty string for the buffer
  buffer = ""

# Read the stream by line
  http.stream do |chunk|
    buffer += chunk
    while line = buffer.slice!(/.+\r?\n/) #cut each line at newline
      handle_tweet JSON.parse(line) #send each tweet object to handle_tweet method
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: You should learn some basis of ruby language. [Ruby Tutorial](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming) from WikiBooks can be helpful.

Comment: that's what I'm trying to do. thx for the link.

Answer (score 0):

You may use debugger.  The purpose of a debugger such as ruby-debug is to allow you to see what is going on “inside” a Ruby program while it executes.
OR you may use logger. Logger  provides a simple but sophisticated logging utility that you can use to display output messages.

Comment: all you need to know about logger: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html